# Fields disappear for a specific theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm new to drupal, so sorry in advance or any mistake, feel free to correct.

I don't really know what exactly that I have done cause the problem, but content's fields (for all content types)
is not being shown (the pages are empty beside the title).
When I edit the information it appears.
In the past the information appeared.
It happens only for a specific theme (business_theme), for other themes (drupal's default) the info' appears.

any idea or help will be great

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `Main page content` block to a region that already exists in your theme.

**First**; Declare the region in your theme's `.info` file.

> regions[content] = Main Content

**Second**; Print the region inside your `page.tpl.php` file.

```
print render($page['content']);
```

**Last**; Assign the `Main page content` to the region from the Blocks manager page. `?q=admin/structure/block`

Comment: I'm not the theme developer (Although I generally understood what you wrote). I think we didn't update any configuration file in the theme except to style.css and views-view...tpl.php. I think that all the contents are being connected to a valid block, but i'll further investigate for this direction.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, It seems that when our own theme is being the default, no node.tpl.php is being called (does that makes sense?).
I add the code

```
<?php
  print '<pre>';
  var_dump(get_defined_vars());
 print '</pre>';
?>
```

to each node*.tpl.php file and cleared all caches.
when our theme is working no changes appeared, 
when enabling batrick theme the added code was working.

This happens only in the page itself, i.e. when entering to localhost/drupal/node...
in the front page the added code worked for both themes.

any ideas?

tnx